Can I use identified charts about a point to get a global canonical coordinate system? Does it induce well defined tangent and cotangent structures?
This question concerns some of the notation I've seen in textbooks of manifold theory. Lee mentions certain representatives of coordinates, but I haven't seen him mentioning this structure explicitly or in a formalized way. Of course, I may have just misread him at some point.  I want to know if what I'm calling in my head a "global canonical coordinate" is a satisfactory or well defined concept. If there is already an explicitly given structure for the this concept, let me know where to find it in a textbook. Otherwise, yes or no answers to each part of the question are satisfactory. Now:

I want to discuss not just one unique maximal atlas on a manifold, but rather the collection of unique atlases on the manifolds we are discussing. Have $A_j = \{ (U_{ij}, \varphi_{ij}) \}_i$ be some maximal atlas, and $\mathfrak A = \{ A_j \}_j$ be the set of maximal all atlases for each manifold we are looking at.

To prevent pathological cases for embedded submanifolds, have it so that $p$ is a member of only one manifold at once.  Have $\Phi_p = \{ \varphi_{ij}(p) \mid  \text{$U_{ij}$ contains $p$}\}$ The relation $\sim$ reduces the set to a single point/equivalence class representative. That is, have $\sim \Phi_p = [\varphi_{ij}(p)]$ Now define $x(p) = \; \sim \Phi_p $.
(1.1) Is this map well defined and unique?
(1.2) Is an induced equivalence class $[\,(\partial / \partial x^i)]$ well defined in this system?
(1.3) There is a map $f: M \rightarrow N$. Is $x \mapsto x(f(p))$ well defined?
(1.4)   Is the pullback of a form $f^* d x = d (x \circ f(p))$ well defined?

I believe the answer to all four subquestions is yes.
There will be only one equivalence class for each $p$. The collection of all maximal atlases is unique. (1.1) is satisfied.
The tangent spaces are all homeomorphic to each other, so (1.2) makes sense as an induced map.
The function maps points with well defined equivalence classes from (1.1). Not only does this function hold, but since $x$ is uniquely distinguishable, we could expand the definition of $f$ and have it serve also as a unique operator $x(f(p)) = (f^* (x)) (p) = (f(x)) (p)$, which matches with the classic definition of $f(x)$.
I also think (1.4) holds, which makes $x$ well defined for both a form of a manifold and its pullback. If this all works, then it saves me a lot of bandwidth thinking about forms and pullbacks, since I have a way to think of just one pseudo-coordinate system.
